# Alternative to readfile()

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, readfile

I'm currently using the following code to download files from my Amazon S3 account.

```
if(isset($_POST['file_name'])) {
$bucket = $_POST['bucket'];
$fname = $_POST['file_name'];
$accessKey = 'AKIAIEHFBME6F5Q62FTQ';
$secretKey = '<REMOVED>';
$file_type = pathinfo($fname, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$mp3_url = el_s3_getTemporaryMP3Link($accessKey, $secretKey, $bucket, $fname);    
$zip_url = el_s3_getTemporaryZipLink($accessKey, $secretKey, $bucket, $fname);


if ($file_type === "mp3") {
    header('Content-type: audio/mpeg3');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="themixtapesite_'.$fname.'"');
    readfile($mp3_url);
    exit();
} else if ($file_type === "zip") {
    header('Content-type: application/zip');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="themixtapesite_'.$fname.'"');
    readfile($zip_url);
    exit();
} else {
    echo "Sorry, File does not exist";
}
```

}

As you can see it checks what the file extension is then passes the relevant url in to `read file()`

The whole point of me using S3 is to lighten my EC2 server loads. 
However, it seems using this method to download the files it pulling the files from S3 via the EC2 server (monitoring the server loads via iStat shows me an increase in activity when downloading a file).

Is there an alternative way of doing this so the file is downloaded directly from S3 rather than via the EC2 server??

UPDATE: Just a quick update - I'm using Nginx rather than apache so no .htaccess if anybody was thinking of suggesting that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a publicly accessible url, or signed url. You can pass that directly to the client using a location redirect.

`header('Location: ' . $myUrl);`

Comment: Thanks, but my problem with that is if the file is an MP3 it just plays in the browser. I want to force the download of that file. I thought `Content-Disposition: attachment;` was supposed to tell the browser to download the file instead of play it, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything if i change `readfile()` to `header('location ...)`

Comment: You should be able to set headers with the file on s3. I've never tried to set a content-disposition header this way, but it might work.

Comment: Sorry, you've lost me there?

Comment: When you store a file on s3, you can also set 1 or more headers. These headers will be passed with the file when downloaded. You should be able to set a content disposition header to allow the file to be directly downloaded from s3.

Comment: ah right, i didn't actually know you could set additional headers. i'll look in to that. thanks.

Comment: Accepted answer, as although the `header('Location...` didn't work the tip off about setting S3 headers has lead me to finding the answer i need. Thanks