# Offering a remote file to download

Tags: php

I offer a zip file download with PHP like this:

```
header("Content-Type: application/zip");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"");
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($location));

readfile($location);
```

How can I handle that when the file is located on a remote server like S3 or dropbox (where I have the rights of course)

I don't like any redirection cause the users shouldn't see the original location.

Do I have to download the file and (temporary) store it on the server?

Comment: Define "store". If direct connection between your visitor's browser and CDN is not desirable, your server will obviously have to act as proxy but you can download it as many times as you want.

Comment: If the users clicks on a link like http://server1.com/file.zip (s)he shouldn't noticed that the file is actually located on http://server2.com/file.zip

Comment: You can read from one stream and send to another, but then your server will still have to download the whole file - just not to store it anywhere. If you want to exclude this part as well, redirection is the only choice, I suppose.

Comment: if you're just providing a file that's not local to your server, you're just proxying that file... unless you have good reason not to, why not just point the user at the file's real location so you're not doubling bandwidth usage on your server?

Comment: @MarcB '... cause the user shouldn't see the original location', I suppose.

Comment: I'm using S3 (for instance) to store all files and my server does some verification to allow users to get the file. In the end I like to decide where the files are stored but I like to offer them through that server with the verification

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment because I thought I had completely misunderstood the question. It almost sounds like the reason you don't want users to see the real file location is because having this knowledge would allow them to bypass the verification... If that's the case, I would strongly recommend you reconsider this approach. That's NOT how to do secure authentication.

Comment: @GVH thanks and valid point. I've just found another thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15006380/alternative-to-readfile I think its a good solution just wonder how others would handle that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can (and possibly *should*!) store the file locally, but you do not *have* to.

So there are a few possible solutions here. These examples assume that $filename has either been safely generated or has been sanitized with something like:

```
$filename = preg_replace('/[^\w.]/', '', $filename); //sanitize
```

1) readfile, with allow_url_fopen enabled:
(see http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php for further details)

```
readfile("http://url/to/your/$filename");
```

2) something more cacheingy, like:

```
// Serve a file from a remote server.
function serveFile($filename) {
    // Folder to locally cache files. Ensure your php user has write access.
    $cacheFolder = '/path/to/some/cache/folder';
    // URL to the folder you'll be downloading from.
    $remoteHost = 'http://remote.host/path/to/folder/';

    $cachedFile = "$cacheFolder$filename";

    // Cache the file if we haven't already.
    if (!file_exists($cachedFile)) {
        // May want to test these two calls, and log failures.
        file_put_contents($cachedFile, file_get_contents("$remoteHost$filename"));
    }
    else {
        // Set the last accessed time.
        touch($cachedFile);
    }
    readfile($cachedFile) or die ("Well, shoot");

    // Optionally, clear old files from the cache.
    clearOldFiles($cacheFolder);
}

// Clear old files from cache folder, based on last mtime.
// Could also clear depending on space used, etc.
function clearOldFiles($cacheFolder) {
    $maxTime = 60 * 60 * 24; // 1 day: use whatever works best.
    if ($handle = opendir($cacheFolder)) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
           if ((time() - filemtime($path.$file)) > $maxTime) {
               unlink($path.$file);
          }
       }
   }
}
```

3) Use CURL, if you do not have access to enable allow_url_fopen.

4) Use an external program like wget if you do not have CURL installed and cannot install it.

5) Worst case: open a socket to port 80 on the remote server, and just send a HTTP request for the file.

6) Your web server may be able to do some kind of proxying redirect that means you don't actually need any code to accomplish this, and you would get caching and other optimizations for free. For example, see the documentation on mod_proxy for Apache here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html

Option 6 is the best if you at all can. Other than that, the first two are the most likely to be needed, but I can fill in some example code for the others if you like :)

Comment: Thanks for that answer! Since I'm using this in a WordPress plugin I can't rely on mod_proxy but I have built in methods which can be used. So it's a mix of 2 and 3